# Is there any way to implement Quick Filter in server-side model ag-grid?

Tags: javascript, filtering, ag-grid

I have implemented server-side model in ag-grid with javascript, I tried with `setQuickFilter` function to implement global search but its not working for me. Is there any way to implement this stuff?

I tried with below code but its not working in server side model.

In HTML file:

```
<input type="text" id="filter-text-box" placeholder="Filter..." oninput="onFilterTextBoxChanged()"/>
```

In JS file:

```
function onFilterTextBoxChanged() {
    gridOptions.api.setQuickFilter(document.getElementById('filter-text-box').value);
}
```

reference : https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-quick/

Comment: What do you mean by global search? For me, this means searchable anywhere on the application.

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and provide us with the necessary code to be able to help you

Comment: please refer : https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-quick/

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/53540080/470749

Answer (score 0):

No, Quick filter works only with client side data model.