# How to use Quick Filter with Server-side / Infinite row model?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

As per [documentation: Quick Filter](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-quick/#server-side-data), quick filter works with `clientSide` row model.

We are using `serverSide` row model for [ag-grid](/questions/tagged/ag-grid) and we have a requirement to use quick filter with the data we have at client - in the cache blocks of the grid.

I though of using filter pipe with `[rowData]="myRowData"`, but with this row model, I don't get any data from `myRowData`.

> For example, if you have a look at this plunk [Server side row model - quick filter](https://plnkr.co/edit/lQcwDzfaBoh5OASj2d9e?p=preview), I have assigned `[rowData]="rowData"` in the markup and initialised it as `[]`.
>
> After loading initial chunk from server, *I was assuming* that the cache block data should be accessible with it, so that using angular pipe, I would be able to filter out the data at client side (mimicking the quick filter with `serverSide` row model). Something like `[rowData]="rowData | filter: filterText"` - like what we used to do in [angularjs](/questions/tagged/angularjs)

But I'm afraid the cache data are not accessible with `rowData`.

How can we somehow use Quick Filter with ag-grid having `serverSide` row model?

Comment: provide a short sample pls, for playing workaround

Comment: updated the question with link to the plunk

Comment: I can't say enough thank you for asking this question. This is exactly what I was looking and the answer given solved the problem and save me lots of working and debugging hours. This community is the best for developers like getting in triouble often times.

Answer (score 5):

I would say it wasn't an easy task.

But here is how it could be solved:

1. As you already mentioned [`quickFilter`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-quick/) is a `clientSide` model type feature
2. But no one has cancelled the [`setFilterModel`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filtering/#example-get-set-all-filter-models) way of usages

   > It would require a lot of hacks and could break something (you have to check it on your solution and write a feedback then)

First of all, `setFilterModel` can't work with virtual data (we have to define `column` especially for `quickFilter` logic)

```
{
    field:'-', would be used as a reference
    hide:true, - hide in grid data
    lockVisible:true, - disable visibility changing via menu
    filter:"agTextColumnFilter", - require for setFilterModel
    filterParams:{
      newRowsAction: "keep"
    }
},
```

Next, we need to create a workaround for `filterModel` in `datasource`

```
getRows: function(params) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var dataAfterSortingAndFiltering = sortAndFilter(data, params.sortModel, params.filterModel);
        var rowsThisPage = dataAfterSortingAndFiltering.slice(params.startRow, params.endRow);
        var lastRow = -1;
        if (dataAfterSortingAndFiltering.length <= params.endRow) {
            lastRow = dataAfterSortingAndFiltering.length;
        }
        params.successCallback(rowsThisPage, lastRow);
    }, 3000);
}

function sortAndFilter(allOfTheData, sortModel, filterModel) {
  return sortData(sortModel, filterData(filterModel, allOfTheData));
}
function sortData(sortModel, data) {
  ... sort logic here (doesn't matter for now) ...
}
```

Now about `quickFilter` logic, we've defined `dummy` column for it and here how it should be used:

setFilterModel will accept only existing column name (*"-" in our case*)

and with limited object props: but we will use `filter` (as it used in real cases)

```
applyFilter(){
    this.gridApi.setFilterModel({"-":{filter: this.filterText}})
}
```

and the last point of implementation is `filterData` function

```
function filterData(filterModel, data) {
  let filterPresent = filterModel && Object.keys(filterModel).length > 0;
  if (!filterPresent) { - if filter model is empty - skip it
    return data;
  }
  data = data.filter(i=>{
    if(Object.keys(i).some(k => i[k] && i[k].toString().toLowerCase().includes(filterModel['-'].filter)))
      return i;
  })
  return data;
}
```

Each object would be explored, and if any property contains `quickFilter` value - it would be in the result

> Moreover, once you will scroll out of existing range (infinite scroll case) requested data would be filtered by this property

*not sure about duplicated data check on request

My <kbd>[**sample**](https://plnkr.co/edit/qThVzOuVqgvijQVrlCtX?p=preview)</kbd>

Your modified <kbd>[**sample**](https://plnkr.co/edit/mWUmwOBAV5wjBEhwkMV5?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for your effort! Que: So when I use `setFilterModel` it anyways calls `dataSource.getRows` and calls server to fetch the data. It's just filter we are applying at the client side. Am I correct? If so, my aim is just to avoid the server trip by applying the filter with whatever data available at client.

Comment: Seems so (about anyway server trip), I've tried to find a way to get data from cache but didn't get the clue.
moreover, it doesn't request all count (as was loaded) and only operates with first block.
*so I suppose ag-grid for now doesn't provide a possibility to handle your case, cuz even if you will try to update data directly it will throw the warning that for service-side model `setRowData` method is restricted.

Comment: This answer guided me in the right direction to solving this problem and save me lots of working and debugging hours. Super explanation and a great guide. Thank you for contibuting to this very essential developers' community. The filterData method is a little bit complex when dealing with more than one column with different data types. I hope to find time to create a demo plunker for this and share it here for others as well.

Answer (score 2):

**Eventually I found ag-Grid's support article:**

https://ag-grid.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360020488612?input_string=serverside+quick+filter

Its first example suggests to edit the `getRows` of your `ServerSideDatasource` to append to `params.request` a new key.

For example, you could do something like the following:

```
const customParams = {};
customParams.quickFilterValue = 'someQuery';
```

In `onGridReady`:

```
const datasource = createServerSideDatasource(server, customParams);
event.api.setServerSideDatasource(datasource)
```

```
/**
 *
 * @param {object} server
 * @param {object} customParams
 * @returns {object}
 */
export function createServerSideDatasource(server, customParams) {
  // https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-server-side-model-datasource/

  return {
    getRows: function (params) {
      params.request.customParams = customParams // Our backend will need to handle this custom 'customParams' key that the frontend attaches to the request (which itself will contain a quickFilterValue key and maybe others).

      const response = server.getData(params.request);

      if (response.success) {
        params.successCallback(response.rows, response.lastRow);
      } else {
        params.failCallback();
      }

    },
  };
}
```